# Можно ли дожидаться данных для страницы прежде, чем перенаправлять на нее пользователя в spa на angular 1?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, spa

Есть проект на первом Angular. Есть главная "страница" и "страница" товаров. Список товаров приходит с бекенда по аяксу и задержка может составлять до 3 секунд. При переходе по ссылке с главной на товары, сначала отображается пустая "страница" с шапкой и футером, и уже через 1-3 секунды, когда пришел список товаров с бекенда, рендерится список товаров.

Вопрос: есть ли инструментарий в ангуляре (из коробки или подключаемый), позволяющий сделать так, чтобы при клике по ссылке, переход происходил бы не сразу а только после того, как придет список товаров? Чтобы не показывать юзеру пустую страницу, а перенаправлять его только, когда для этой страницы пришли данные.

PS: использую ui-router

Comment: `resolve` - должен помочь

Comment: Спасибо, буду копать в этом направлении

Comment: На англ стаковерфлоу подсказали хороший пример http://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-resolve-angularjs-resources-with-ui-router/